# appear on hover and stay visible

Tags: html, css

First time asking a question here...

I'm making a drop down menu with some effects that I got from cssdeck.com.
Basically the nav is from one source, and the sub menu from another.
I've mixed two cssdeck.com source to make it look like one.

So far, I got the sub menu to appear on hover, but can't make it stay visible so I can click on the sub menu.

The code is pretty long and complicated and I'm not exactly sure how to show/share it for you to check...

How do I make "A" to appear on "B":hover and make "A" stay visible when I move the pointer to "A" to select something on "A"??????

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav_main ph-dot-nav"> 
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About
            <div id="sub_about">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li_first"><a href="#">회사소개</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#">대표인사말</a> </li>
                    <li class="li_last"><a href="#">회사연혁</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </a>
         <a href="#">Services</a>
         <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
         <a href="#">Partners</a>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/7j214u1y/1/)

Comment: I've created https://jsfiddle.net/7j214u1y/1/ to help you understand my question

Comment: You have `<a href="#">About` which will end as soon as it encounters `</a>` so the anchor ends when it encountered `</a>` in the subnav. You can't have anchor inside anchor. You can [see here](http://css-snippets.com/drop-down-navigation/) how dropdowns are made.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this, if you also show the submenu if you hover on it. See
https://jsfiddle.net/7xfrod2s/

```
#sub_about:hover {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Also I moved the `visible: hidden` style to the parents tag of `ul` (`#sub_about`).

Maybe you need an other `:before` tag so that there is no gap between the header and the submenu (a curser-bridge so to say) ;)

Answer (score 0):

To achive this with CSS there's are rules your need to stick with. First take a look as this pic.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbR5J.png
(I'd love it, if someone help me post a pic)

- must be have no space in between your `Menu` tag and `subMenu`. It will fail if there is 1px in between thse element.
- use the simple hover stage like follow
- subMenu must be children of Menu

hide the `subMenu`

```
.subMenu{
    display: none;
}
```

make `subMenu` appear when you hover on its parent or itself

```
.menu:hover .subMenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Explaination: the hover state of DOM quite simple. if you are hovering on a `child element` it also mean that you are hovering on its parent. So this is while you must not let any space inbetween `Menu`and `subMenu`. Because the movement your cursor hover on that 1px for 1ms the DOM will understand as the hover state over. So it will hide the `subMenu` away

*For example:* in the pic. Pretending like your submenu not hiding, so if you are hovering on `subMenu` the DOM also understand as you are also hovering on `Menu` (parent menu)