# horizontal drop down menu with horizontal submenu

Tags: html, css

great answers I got for the question I posted earlier([appear on hover and stay visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737120/appear-on-hover-and-stay-visible)).

It felt very complicated to edit the css and html becuase I just copy and pasted AND mixed two different css sources up from cssdeck.com to make one nav menu.

So I decided to start from scratch to make a proper drop down menu that looks and behaves exactly like the one I made before.

But..... I'm stuck again with the submenu.

This time, I want to make the submenu horizontal as well, which will then have different width from the nav menu. I used white-space: nowrap to make the submenu horizontal, but now the submenu disappears once I move my mouse close to the next nav menu.

Plus, I can't seem to make the nav menu stay inplace when the submenu appears.

I'm still working on it so the example may look very disorganized. Sorry about that.

help... please..?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2p4fsLk1/ example here

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QwsSw.png this is what I'm aiming to create... is this even possible to make only with css????

Answer (score 1):

Because the submenus are set as `display: block`, elements on the page are flowing around them when they appear. To correct this behaviour, you need to add `position: absolute` to your submenus. If an element is positioned absolutely, other elements on the page will ignore it rather than flow around it. [Read more about positioning and how it affects page flow here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

The submenus are disappearing because you've applied a `margin` of `10px` to the submenu wrappers. Remove that margin and your submenus stay in place as expected.

I noticed, also, that you added `white-space: nowrap` to the "About" submenu `ul`, but not to the other submenu `ul`s. [Here's a JSFiddle with those fixes applied](https://jsfiddle.net/qx7amr9d/2/).

On a broader note, your HTML/CSS is in dire need of some TLC:

- The `div` wrappers around your `ul`s are redundant. Just use the `ul`s themselves.
- Using classes like `li_first` and `li_last` is unnecessary, because we can select the first/last children with the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes.
- Use generic classes instead of IDs, e.g. `.submenu` instead of `#subAbout`, `#subServ`, etc.

Applying the above ideas will eliminate any duplication or unnecessary specificity in your code, which is something you should strive to do. Your CSS will be a fraction of the length, much more readable/maintainable/debuggable, and you won't run into issues like forgetting to add that `white-space` property mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/Team_Exitium/34ueyguh/11/

here is live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Team_Exitium/34ueyguh/11/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul id="top-ul">
            <li class="main"><a href="">Home</a>

                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a>sdfsadfasdf</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>sjhfasdhljfdha</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main"><a href="">About</a>

                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a>sdfsadfasdf</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>sjhfasdhljfdha</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main"><a href="">Service</a>

                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a>sdfsadfasdf</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>sjhfasdhljfdha</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    body {margin:0;}

nav {width: 100%;height: 40px;}

#top-ul {height: 25px; margin:0;}
li {

    float:left;

    padding-right:55px;

    list-style-type:none;

}

a {

    font-family:"Unica One", "Noto Reg", sans-serif;

    font-size: 1.5em;

    color: #393939;

    text-decoration:none;

}

.sub {

    position:absolute;

    display:none;

    background-color: #c6342e;

    top: 35px;

    padding-left: 5px;

    font-family:"Noto Lgt", sans-serif;

    font-size: 12pt;

    border-radius:8px;

}

.sub a {

    color: #fff;

}

.sub a:hover {

    background-color: #d46762;

}

.sub li {

    padding-right: 25px;

}
.main {margin-top:5px; height:35px;}
.main:hover > ul {

    display:block;

}
```